# From autoit script the program is not taking the "#1" value from the password field

Tags: selenium, autoit

For windows authentication using selenium I am using the below autoit script but the program is not taking the "#1" value from

```
WinWaitActive("Windows Security")

Send("Test\1234")

Send("{TAB}")

Send("testen#1")

Send("{ENTER}")
```

program is reading only "testen" , its not reading "#1"... 
Can someone suggest a solution for this..?

Answer (score 2):

From [Send](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) documentation:

> '#'
>
> The hash now sends a Windows keystroke; therefore, Send("#r") would send Win+r which launches the Run() dialog box.

If you look at the top of the table in the Remarks section, you may see:

Send: `{#}`

Result: `#`

Using `{#}` stops `#` being sent as a Windows keystroke and instead sends the literal character `#`.

So use:

```
Send("testen{#}1")
```

or you could try the raw parameter of Send().